# Python: Parse dita map file and contents and output all href values

Tags: python, xml, dita

I'm a newbie Python programmer, and I was looking for a script or snippet to help. I have to parse a dita map/xml file and for every xml file, output that filename, open that file and search for referenced `.dita`, `.ditamap`, or `.xml` file, output their filename, and recurse into those files. The ideas is to output a file of all the files referenced by that `.ditamap/xml` file and its children. This file will feed a list for zipping that group of files to send for processing.
I found some sample code but I get no output!

```
import os
import glob
root_dir ='~/test_folder'
for filename in glob.glob(root_dir + '**/*.xml', recursive=True)
    print(filename)
```

Here is a sample ditamap file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?Inspire CreateDate="2019-04-04T16:06:14" ModifiedDate="2022-11-11T16:44:57"?><!DOCTYPE bookmap PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA BookMap//EN" "bookmap.dtd">

<bookmap id="bookmap_e90eb827-7421-4491-8df3-5fea34a44931" xml:lang="en-US">
    <booktitle id="booktitle_a78ddf49-09d7-4d3d-925c-d42d9ff7f360">
        <mainbooktitle id="mainbooktitle_0a34f716-bedc-4c5d-b198-dfd5006a3174">About the Documentation</mainbooktitle>
    </booktitle>
    <bookmeta>
        <prodinfo>
            <prodname />
            <vrmlist>
                <vrm version="1" />
            </vrmlist>
            <!--Do not change: Must be Manual-->
            <brand>Manual</brand>
        </prodinfo>
        <!--sets task labels (1st othermeta tag below)-->
        <othermeta content="yes" name="task-labels" />
        <othermeta content="about" name="bundle" />
        <bookid>
            <!--Revision-->
            <volume>A0X</volume>
        </bookid>
        <bookrights>
            <copyrfirst>
                <!--Format of copyright year is yyyy - mm-->
                <year>2019 - 04</year>
            </copyrfirst>
            <bookowner>
                <!--Do not change organization-->
                <organization>Dell</organization>
            </bookowner>
        </bookrights>
    </bookmeta>
    <chapter href="subjectscheme_6b1f4589-e73e-49be-806d-0d064f3efd01.xml" format="ditamap" outputclass="subjectscheme" processing-role="resource-only" scope="external" />
    <chapter href="atm-About_user_guide_891d23dc-a186-422d-af40-75249dd31f87.xml">
        <topicmeta>
            <navtitle>About the <keyword conref="lib-Boomi_Keywords_0346af2b-13d7-491e-bec9-18c5d89225bf.xml#GUID-0207C7F1-40FD-4537-BE59-1D6DA46B9A1D/BOOMI_DELL" /><keyword conref="lib-Boomi_Keywords_0346af2b-13d7-491e-bec9-18c5d89225bf.xml#GUID-0207C7F1-40FD-4537-BE59-1D6DA46B9A1D/BOOMI_ATOMSPHERE" /> User Guide</navtitle>
        </topicmeta>
        <topicref href="atm-Content_browsing_2c16a734-5cf8-416c-8978-0062ac04e430.xml">
            <topicmeta>
                <navtitle>Content browsing</navtitle>
            </topicmeta>
        </topicref>
        <topicref href="atm-Content_searching_acdba241-6d33-41bc-8886-0907906fed64.xml">
            <topicmeta>
                <navtitle>Content searching</navtitle>
                <othermeta name="mini-toc" content="yes" />
            </topicmeta>
        </topicref>
        <topicref href="atm-Creating_a_documentation_account_c4ddf038-e007-4ee3-bef9-9f4eb06d0f89.dita" />
        <topicref href="atm-Collections_of_your_favorite_topics_5dd10ed2-b689-4628-bc2c-bc35dd4f571e.xml">
            <topicref id="topicref_bb2f9a40-0266-44b5-a061-39eca24b5d41" href="atm-sharing_saved_collections_d41e734f-4b2e-4c1e-82e7-91617d1008ae.dita" navtitle="atm-Sharing_saved_collections" type="task" />
        </topicref>
        <topicref id="topicref_8a2ba548-6595-4cc5-af12-afa2631abfbb" href="atm-Using_table_filters_178c0de0-ddee-4073-b828-476ad13345c4.dita" type="task" />
        <topicref href="atm-Team_welcomes_your_feedback_848e635e-0132-43d8-b22d-bbdf87ca398a.xml">
            <topicmeta>
                <navtitle>The <keyword conref="lib-Boomi_Keywords_0346af2b-13d7-491e-bec9-18c5d89225bf.xml#GUID-0207C7F1-40FD-4537-BE59-1D6DA46B9A1D/BOOMI_ATOMSPHERE">The T</keyword> documentation team welcomes your feedback</navtitle>
            </topicmeta>
        </topicref>
        <topicref href="atm-Other_ways_to_get_help_09adc783-784f-4f15-87f9-672d8030b689.xml">
            <topicmeta>
                <navtitle>Other ways to get help</navtitle>
            </topicmeta>
        </topicref>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <topicref href="atm-Terms_of_use_78ffba54-261d-428d-afcd-a9db3ce51123.dita" />
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <topicref>
            <topicref href="atm-API_licensing_df074d66-3a10-4df5-8dd5-0a3e13373d0e.dita" />
        </topicref>
    </chapter>
    <backmatter>
        <topicref href="r-boo-Copyright_Boomi_Online_Help_9eea563b-53a2-4d69-b6e7-7372bf7d5440.xml" navtitle="Copyright">
            <topicmeta>
                <navtitle>CopyrightBoomiOnlineHelp</navtitle>
            </topicmeta>
        </topicref>
        <topicref href="atm-About_reltable_72640fe6-ae6d-490c-b369-7adbcb67bc99.xml" linking="normal" print="no" toc="no">
            <topicmeta>
                <navtitle>reltable</navtitle>
            </topicmeta>
        </topicref>
    </backmatter>
</bookmap>
```

If anyone can help or have a similar script that would traverse and parse the files, that would be great!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Russ

Comment: I added my script sample I found. Sorry about that!

Comment: @RussUrquhart this list all xml files but not explizit the dita files. It also not read the links from dita map. Would you like to share also a dita file for parsing?

Comment: I'll add it to my original post? Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the `href` like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("bookmap.dita")
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter():
    if 'href' in elem.attrib:
        # print tag name and file reference
        print(elem.tag, elem.get('href'))
```

Output:

```
chapter subjectscheme_6b1f4589-e73e-49be-806d-0d064f3efd01.xml
chapter atm-About_user_guide_891d23dc-a186-422d-af40-75249dd31f87.xml
topicref atm-Content_browsing_2c16a734-5cf8-416c-8978-0062ac04e430.xml
topicref atm-Content_searching_acdba241-6d33-41bc-8886-0907906fed64.xml
topicref atm-Creating_a_documentation_account_c4ddf038-e007-4ee3-bef9-9f4eb06d0f89.dita
topicref atm-Collections_of_your_favorite_topics_5dd10ed2-b689-4628-bc2c-bc35dd4f571e.xml
topicref atm-sharing_saved_collections_d41e734f-4b2e-4c1e-82e7-91617d1008ae.dita
topicref atm-Using_table_filters_178c0de0-ddee-4073-b828-476ad13345c4.dita
topicref atm-Team_welcomes_your_feedback_848e635e-0132-43d8-b22d-bbdf87ca398a.xml
topicref atm-Other_ways_to_get_help_09adc783-784f-4f15-87f9-672d8030b689.xml
topicref atm-Terms_of_use_78ffba54-261d-428d-afcd-a9db3ce51123.dita
topicref atm-API_licensing_df074d66-3a10-4df5-8dd5-0a3e13373d0e.dita
topicref r-boo-Copyright_Boomi_Online_Help_9eea563b-53a2-4d69-b6e7-7372bf7d5440.xml
topicref atm-About_reltable_72640fe6-ae6d-490c-b369-7adbcb67bc99.xml
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This gives me everything in the ditamap. Is there a way, after it outputs the above, it then goes into each subsequent xml/dita/ditmap file, and begins searching recursively?

Comment: Sure. Would you search than in the subsequent dita, or xml or both? And what should be the result? Not clear.

Comment: You would search in the dita, xml, or ditamap, searching for more of the same files. A recursive search. Does that make sense?

Comment: What should be the stop condition of the recursion? Do you have a leaf xml without any link? How many levels up will you search? To prevent an endless loop, you should define what should be the stop condition. What will you do with all this links in a list? Sorry I don’t know for what this dita files are used for. You can write my lines of code in a function and call this function for each link in the list of links.

Comment: I was thinking you'd have a Stack mechanism. As you parse through a file, each filename you find, is put on the stack. If that file has already been processed don't put it on the stack. When you've found all the files in the current file, you Pop the file off the stack and start over again. You continue until the Stack is empty. Or that was what I was thinking.

Comment: Exactly, but if the link is pop'ed from the list you doesn't know that you have processed it. Any way what is the stop condition, if each XML or dita have some links again and again.

Comment: Does Python support like an associatve array? You could store your alread processed links/files there before you pop?

Comment: @RussUrquhart Could you please share a topicref -> xml and a topicref -> dita ?  topicref can refer to dita or xml, what is the difference? ditamap is the root? You can do something like [filename, [list of filenames]]. In your example it looks like all referenced files are in the same directory?

Comment: The naming conventions of the cms, removes any file structure from the file names. To go around this, i created a directory of all the files. The names are unique, so it is a flat file data architecture. For these set of files, even though we start reading from a ditamap file, any of the files parsed, can and do include, .xml, .dita, .ditamap files, which each have to be opened and parsed for more files. As we parse through this mess, we just want to have a list of the unique file names that are referenced.

Comment: Does the csv from my other answer the job?

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed this code write a csv recursivly (**Be carefully** this program have no stopp condition as I asked you. It will stop only, maybe with Error if the first file without links will be found or the file can’t be found):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Dita:
    """write a csv file with file name and included file list """
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file_name = file
        self.file_list = []
             
    def parse_dita(self, file_name):
        tree = ET.parse(file_name)
        root = tree.getroot()
        
        file_list = []
        for elem in root.iter():
            if 'href' in elem.attrib:
                row = elem.get('href') #elem.tag,
                file_list.append(row)
        
        row = file_name, str(file_list),'\n'
        with open("f_and_links.csv", 'a') as f_and_links:
            f_and_links.writelines(row)
                    
        return file_list

def main():
    root_file = "bookmap.dita"
    print("Source file:", root_file)
    dita_obj = Dita(root_file)
    file_list = dita_obj.parse_dita(root_file)

    for f in file_list:
        print("Links list", f)
        dita_obj.parse_dita(f)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```